# TwitterKit not returning users email ios

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I am implementing Twitter login on my iOS Application using Twitter Kit.

```
{
let logInButton = TWTRLogInButton(logInCompletion: { session, error in
            if (session != nil) {
                print("signed in as \(session?.userName)");
                self.perform(#selector(ViewController.requestForEmail), with: nil, afterDelay: 5.0)
            } else {
                print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription)");
            }
        })
        logInButton.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(logInButton)
}
```

I am logged in successfully. But when I request for email by below code:

```
{
let client = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser()
        client.requestEmail { email, error in
            if (email != nil) {
                print("signed in as \(email)");
            } else {
                print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription)");
            }
        }}
```

I get this error:

> This user does not have an email address.

I enabled request email address option in twitter app setting and also set privacy and policy URl.

Comment: generally Twitter does not return email id

Comment: Are you certain that the account you are logged in with has a confirmed email address on the Twitter side? i.e. that the address was added, and then the email confirmation link was clicked? The API will not return an address if it is not verified and confirmed.

Comment: Yes, My logged in Twitter email id is email verified.